# Why the code I wrote does not send gsm AT commands

Tags: php, windows, gsm

I am trying to send sms from my vista pc. I tried AT commands from "command windows" and sent sms.  Then, I wrote php code to send sms from php; it opens the port but it does not send sms.

```
 $device = "COM14";
 exec("mode $device : BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 STOP=1");

 $comport = fopen($device, "w+");

 if ($comport === false){
    die("Failed opening com port<br/>");
 }else{
    echo "Com port is open<br/>";
 }

 $smsText="Test message";

 $atcmd1 ='AT+CMGF=1 \r\n';
 $atcmd2 ='AT+CMGS=\"05324370000\"\r\n' . $smsText . chr(26) .'\r\n';

 fputs($comport, $atcmd1);
 fputs($comport, $atcmd2);


 fclose($comport);
```

Comment: There shouldn't be space after `$device` in `mode` command.